How to schedule Automatic Wordpress Core and specifics Plugins updates for specific time a day
Nowadays we are doing manually updates every 2 weeks in a test server, we test all plugins and if everything is ok. We deploy same file changes with Git in production server.
Sometime we found some mayor bugs in plugins or our theme. That's why we test before deployment.
We are thinking to change our workflow. Maybe we can test all updates in test and programate production server to do update only for plugins that passed the tests. And remove Core files from Git.
We don't want to update plugins within business hours.
Is there a way to schedule for after 1 am a specific day, but for specifics plugins, theme and/or Core ?

Not as part of WordPress, but I use wp-cli (commands like wp core update and wp plugin update --all, for example) and schedule it using cron. If you're on a non-Linux/Unix system, there should still be some kind of task scheduling system available.

I just check documentation for wp plugin update and I can specify some plugins. This the way!!!.
